linker error when attempting to run C program in WSL environment
When attempting to compile a test program cc test.c -o test in an Ubuntu WSL environment, I get the output of:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory

I've already attempted most of the solutions posted in the most popular post for this issue. I didn't see repeated attempts to open(...crti.o) = -1 ENOENT when doing gcc -print-search-dirs either. This was the output code for that following command if it's any help:
install: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/
programs: =/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/
libraries: =/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/

